# I can't find the issue or pull request in the C++ draft GitHub, supporting the change below in [basic.start.static]/2

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

N4791 - 2018-12-07 (This coincides with the wording in the [current draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#static-2) for [basic.start.static]/2)

> Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object
>   with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant
>   initializer (7.7) for the entity. If constant initialization is not
>   performed, a variable with static storage duration (6.6.4.1) or thread
>   storage duration (6.6.4.2) is zero-initialized (9.3). Together,
>   zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static
>   initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization.
>   All static initialization strongly happens before (6.8.2.1) any
>   dynamic initialization. [Note: The dynamic initialization of non-local
>   variables is described in 6.8.3.3; that of local static variables is
>   described in 8.7. — end note]

N4778 - 2018-10-08 (This is the draft preceding N4791)

> A constant initializer for a variable or temporary object o is an
>   initializer whose full-expression is a constant expression, except
>   that if o is an object, such an initializer may also invoke constexpr
>   constructors for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of
>   non-literal class types. [Note: Such a class may have a non-trivial
>   destructor. — end note] Constant initialization is performed if a
>   variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is
>   initialized by a constant initializer for the entity. If constant
>   initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage
>   duration (6.6.4.1) or thread storage duration (6.6.4.2) is
>   zero-initialized (9.3). Together, zero-initialization and constant
>   initialization are called static initialization; all other
>   initialization is dynamic initialization. All static initialization
>   strongly happens before (6.8.2.1) any dynamic initialization. [Note:
>   The dynamic initialization of non-local variables is described in
>   6.8.3.3; that of local static variables is described in 8.7. — end note]

Comment: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2442

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks a lot. I was looking for an issue or pull-request containing the string "[basic.start.static]" with no results.

Comment: You could look to the history of `basic.tex` for commits between the dates.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Great tip. This was the first time I looked at `source` and it was so much more simple to find what I wanted. I'm delighted that you brought this to my attention.Thank you.

Comment: Or, even better, look at Blame for `basic.tex`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yeah! That's even better. Thanks again.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Would you mind making that an answer, so that this question disappears from the language lawyer unanswered question list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the answer from a comment so that this question disappears from the unanswered question list: the relevant pull request is http://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2442